# to get memory address of variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, memory

I have a variable in the power shell as below

```
$x
```

Please help me to get the memory address of $x

Comment: Why do you need it? If you're using WINAPI functions then there are many examples showing how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to use kernel32.dll functions. I couldn't find one in google. may be I am bad it search. @wOxxOm